# Trouble getting .gitignore files to work on OSX and Tower git GUI

Tags: gitignore

I have a cache directory I'm trying to have ignored by git which lives in my CMS's root directory here:

```
/files/cache/
```

I've tried the following variations in a .gitignore file at the root of the project:

```
/files/cache
/files/cache/*
files/cache
files/cache/*
```

But the files still show up in Tower ready to be staged - the only other thing I can think of is that I'm using comments in the file like this:

```
# comment
/files/cache
```

Just not sure what I've missed sorry - any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are the files in question untracked? Please note that files that are already tracked by Git can't be ignored. In that case you'd have to untrack them and commit the deletion, first.
2. In Tower's "Status" view, which view mode do you use?
   If we're talking about folders (not only individual files) matched by a pattern, "ALL" mode will continue to show the folder as untracked (while also hiding individual files). "MODIFIED" will hide the matched patterns completely.

Comment: Yes they're tracked. Thank you, I now understand what's going on - I'm trying to exclude them after my initial commit. Is there a way to untracked them by matching a pattern or do I have to untracked all of these cache files manually? These files seemed to be owned by the MAMP www user and are causing all sorts of issues in Tower - like endlessly redrawing an alert dialogue box until I force quit the app.

Comment: I've been trying the following: `git rm --cached file.to.remove` but keep getting the following error `-bash: git: command not found` which I don't really understand as git is installed - unless Tower installs a version?

Comment: I'm not sure how Tower is making branches and doing commits but I guess git isn't installed because I can't seem to run any git command locally in the Terminal - will install now.

Comment: Weird, I've just run the git installer but I can't run `git --version` or `git rm -r directory-name`

Comment: Although I know nothing about profile paths, I've tried adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/bin:~/bin` to `~/.profile` but I still can't run `git --version`

Comment: Got it working in OSX lion by: 1. reinstalling git, 2. creating a file called: `.bash_profile` in my user home directory, 3. running: `~/.bash_profile` in the terminal

Comment: So most of my issues with Tower was to do with MAMP running as www/mysql creating all sorts of permissions issues. Now I'm running MAMP as username/username I've been able to remove files from the index, run a commit and then add the cache and tmp directories to my .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

Put this .gitignore in /files/.gitignore

```
cache
```

and commit it.